# File read behavior while reading file from C code

Tags: python, c++, file-io

I am trying to execute a simple code to read a file in which data is written from python script as int32 type

```
# array_values is a numpy array
array_values.astype('int32').tofile(filename + '.dat')
```

The c program to read it is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
typedef unsigned uint32_t;
int main()
{
         char* filename;
         FILE* f;
         uint32_t number;
         filename = "datfile.dat";
         f = fopen(filename, "rb");
         if (f == NULL){
                 printf("File NULL");
         }
         //fseek(f, SEEK_SET, 0);

         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                 fread(&number, 4, 1, f);
                 printf("%d   %08x \n", i, number);
         }


    return 0;
}
```

The code above gives the following result:

```
0   01040000
1   00260e7d
2   0375016c
3   07caf50c
4   0dd90464
5   f8e2f9ea
6   076d0527
7   00c61143
8   113af1de
9   fbb5038b
```

If I change the it to read 2 bytes

```
fread(&number, 2, 1, f);
```

It gives the following output: ( and it is the expected and correct one )

```
0   00000000
1   00000104
2   00000e7d
3   00000026
4   0000016c
5   00000375
6   0000f50c
7   000007ca
8   00000464
9   00000dd9
```

I fail to understand why int32 is not giving the correct result when 4 bytes are read.

EDIT:

Output after using numpy.swapbytes(True) to toggle between the big and little endian before saving data to the file and the output is much more messed up

```
0   00000000
1   00000000
2   00000000
3   0000ffff
4   00000000
5   ffffffff
6   00000000
7   00000000
8   0000ffff
9   ffff0000
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not correct" ? Output looks consistent to me (assuming little endian).

Comment: *"The c program"* ... `#include <iostream>`... Those two don't mix.

Comment: can you have a look at the file using a hex editor?

Comment: BTW what you're doing is undefined behaviour: you just copy 2 bytes in a 4 byte data but `number` is never set to 0 so you could get garbage...

Comment: @SanderDeDycker you are right. I think the endian format is the issue here. I am using a python script to dump some data in dat file, which is read by another application written in c ( it's a proprietary code thus can't change it). It always read it in reverse order. I am not sure if i should do something to explicitly specify endianess while dumping the data from python. @ Jean you are right. I wrote this test prog in hurry and missed couple of things.

Comment: both the reader and the writer need to agree on the byte order in the file. Any way you choose to achieve that should work fine. The common way is to use network byte order (aka big endian) in the file, and to use byte order conversion functions (between host byte order and network byte order) in both the writer and reader (eg. the [`htonl` family](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html)).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thanks. I even tried to use swapbytes method of numpy to toggle between endianess and the output is much worse. have added to the ques.

Comment: python has its [own versions of the `htonl` family](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.ntohl)

Comment: Looks like the file doesn't contain what you expect it to contain. How are you creating the Python array?

Comment: @molbdnilo it does contain the data I need just in reverse order for e.g. `01040000` should be `00000104`. The 'c' application needs it in the later order. I am using simply creating a numpy array filling it with values and then save it to a dat file.

Comment: @blackbug Have you looked at the file itself to determine that? The data you print is not the reverse of the data you're expecting. Each number consists of two of the expected numbers, which suggests that the file actually contains 16-bit integers.